# On a Win Vista Home Premium: What does the Symantec Network Security Intermediat Filter?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking

In the Properties of Wireless Network-Conections there is such a Service activated:

- Exists a replacement by microsoft?
- What does this service exactly?
- may i deinstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the Symantec VPN client.  Do you have that installed?  Was it ever installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed and therefore to see in Network Properties. But i am not aware of a VPN-Setup on this Notebook. I don't know how it comes here in.

Comment: You say it is installed.  Do you mean the Symantec VPN clinet itself or something else? If you uninstall the Symantec VPN clinet, that should remove the entry.  However, if you use the VPN client for somthing, that is a problem.   In some cases, an unistall can fail.

Comment: in properties of the network-connection i can uncheck the checkbox near this service. i think thats is enough to disable this service on this particular network-connection (i have two: LAN and WiFi) isn't it?